# Bootstrap 3 - Fill page container (Fill width and height ) in between a static header and footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a basic bootstrap page using the [Example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/):

Id like to have the content in the middle to fill the space in between both BUT I want the header and footer visible at all times.
So if the content is bigger than the screen, Id like it to scroll, while keeping the header and footer there.

Essentially, I want to use the header and footer as control panels, while having the middle content scroll accordingly with larger content rather than pushing the footer out of sight.

Any ideas?

Thanks
G

Comment: `.container{overflow-y:auto}`

Comment: Got plenty of ideas. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Change the `#footer` `position` from `absolute` to `fixed`

**EDIT:**
Ok here's some guide lines to help you get closer of what you need to do ( some might already be done so just double check)

- `html` and `body` both should have `height: 100%`
- replace `navbar-fixed-top` with `navbar-static-top`
- move the `navbar` inside `container`
- `container` becomes `container-fluid` with `padding: 0`
- you need a padding inside container, you might do that by adding a `row-fluid` that contains the `page-header` and `lead` but not the navs
- remove `position` from `#footer` or set it to `relative`
- add `overflow-y:scroll` to the `container`

Comment: I suppose, what im trying to do is have the div in between the header and footerhave its own scrollbar.?

Comment: so you want to move the scroll bar from a full page scroll to just a div scroll right ?

Comment: Yeah hopefully.
I want it like
<div HEADER, ALWAYS VISIBLE>

<div content, Full page width and height. But with a scrollbar.>

<div FOOTER, Always visible>